# Javascript and User Controls in C#

Tags: c#

I have some JS functions within the ASCX of a user control. This UC is loaded multiple times in the host page. When I do a view source, I see the JS repeated for every instance of the UC.

Is there a way I can have it load the functions only once? I would like to reduce the size of the page for better performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the functions in a separate .js file, then add it by calling Page.[ClientScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx).[RegisterClientScriptInclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptinclude.aspx)().

You can also mark the file as an Embedded Resource, and then include it using Page.ClientScript.[RegisterClientScriptResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptresource.aspx)().

Note that if you're using a ScriptManager/UpdatePanels, use [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx).[RegisterClientScriptInclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptinclude.aspx) or .[RegisterClientScriptResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptresource.aspx) so that it'll know how to add the reference correctly on a partial postback.

Comment: +1 because it was better than my answer - prevents multiple loads of js